# Trying to solve a hackerhank challenge (The PADS), what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want this output:

```
Ashely(P)
Christeen(P)
Jane(A)
Jenny(D)
Julia(A)
Ketty(P)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Priya(S)
Samantha(D)
There are a total of 2 doctors.
There are a total of 2 singers.
There are a total of 3 actors.
There are a total of 3 professors.
```

This is the query:

```
select concat(name,'(',left(occupation,1),')') 
from occupations
order by name;
select concat('There are a total of ', count(*),' ', occupation,'s') from occupations
group by occupation
order by count(occupation);
```

Every time I run it I get this output:

```
Aamina(D)
Ashley(P)
Belvet(P)
Britney(P)
Christeen(S)
Eve(A)
Jane(S)
Jennifer(A)
Jenny(S)
Julia(D)
Ketty(A)
Kristeen(S)
Maria(P)
Meera(P)
Naomi(P)
Priya(D)
Priyanka(P)
Samantha(A)
concat('There are a total of ', count(*),' ', occupation,'s')
There are a total of 3 Doctors
There are a total of 4 Actors
There are a total of 4 Singers
There are a total of 7 Professors
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Good to add table structure to make it easy to understand question for people.

Comment: Why don't you want all the rows you get? A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to edit yet. hahaha

Comment: I don't want the roll "concat('There are a total of ', count(*),' ', occupation,'s')" printed

Comment: Then alias it...

Comment: Maybe you just want to insert a `UNION ALL` in place of the first semicolon, to combine the two queries?

Comment: Thanks!! It works with ALIAS and UNION

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help! It's working now. I've changed the query to:

```
SELECT CONCAT(NAME,'(',LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')') AS RESPONSE  
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
UNION  
SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ',COUNT(OCCUPATION),' ',LOWER(OCCUPATION),'s.') AS RESPONSE  
FROM OCCUPATIONS  
GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
ORDER BY RESPONSE ASC
```